# Add a year column with the length of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of a company clients that have 128 observations, all of them from 2020. As I want to add this data frame with 2021 clients, I would like to add a "Year" column before adding new lines/observations. I have made a 'for' loop to do so, but with no success. My code only returns a 1x1 data frame.

Could you help me?

My code:

```
 for (i in length(clients)) {
      x <- 2020
      b <- rbind(x)
      return(b)
 }
```

It returns:

[1] 2020

instead of a column in my df with "2020" value.

Comment: Please show a small reproducicble example

Comment: this should add a new column ("year_2020") to you data.frame containing 2020 in all rows: clients$year_2020 <- 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use dollar sign to create a new column in R dataframes:

```
clients$Year <- "2020"
```

If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, I think you understand me correctly. I have done what you said and It did what I wanted to do.  Thank you.